# Play framework asynchronous calls in java

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework, promise

Im using the code below to call a webservice. Play's framework non blocking actions are great. The only issue is i want to store the response and manipulate them before i sent them off to the view.

```
public static Promise<JsonNode> classService(String id) {
        String urlS = "www.service.api.com";
        Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = WS.url(urlS).get();
        Promise<JsonNode> resultPromise = responsePromise
                .map(new Function<WSResponse, JsonNode>() {
                    @Override
                    public JsonNode apply(WSResponse response) throws Throwable {
                        JsonNode searchResponse = response.asJson();
                        return searchResponse;
                    }
                });
        return resultPromise;
    }
```

I'm calling the service action in this while loop

```
while(dataIter.hasNext()){   
 JsonNode tempNode = dataIter.next();
 String id = tempNode.path("id").toString();
 classService(id);  
}
```

When i tried storing the data in the while loop, the code breaks(timeout error). So how do i store the data when play is done with a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can set explicit timeout to random milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`F.Promise.sequence()`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#sequence(play.libs.F.Promise...)) to wait for all results before using/storing your data.

So, from your while loop, we're going to store the promises:

```
List<F.Promise<JsonNode>> promises = new ArrayList<F.Promise<JsonNode>>();
while(dataIter.hasNext()){   
   JsonNode tempNode = dataIter.next();
   String id = tempNode.path("id").toString();
   promises.add(classService(id));  
}
```

And then do whatever you need to do with the data as soon as all results are in.

```
F.Promise.sequence(promises).map(new Function<List<JsonNode>, Response>() {
    @Override
    public Response apply(List<JsonNode> data) throws Throwable {
         // Do stuff with your data, or store it wherever
         return ok("Here is the result")
    }
}
```

Of course, if you need to manipulate the data on an `JsonNode` level (i.e., not needing the rest of the collection) you can do it in the map you already have in `classService()`.